# What is the highest power of $18$ contained in $\frac{50!}{25!(50-25)!}$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

What is the highest power of $18$ contained in $\frac{50!}{25!(50-25)!}$?

How will I be able to find the answer to such questions? Is there any special technique to find the answer to such problems? Thank you.

Comment: [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/highest-power-of-a-prime-p-dividing-n) is relevant.

Comment: [This formula may be even more relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/833706/11619) :-) See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/51469/11619).

Comment: @Rohan I don't think it is correct to tamper with original question, even if it is obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$18 = 2\cdot 3^2$. We can find the power of a small prime in a large factorial by successive division to find base divisibility, then divisibility by squares, etc. So the [multiplicity of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $2$ in $50!$, $v_2(50!),$ is
$$ v_2(50!) = \left\lfloor\frac{50}{2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{50}{4}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{50}{8}\right\rfloor + \cdots = 25+12+6+3+1 = 47$$

and similarly $v_2(25!)=22$, $v_3(50!)=16+5+1 = 22$ and $v_3(25!)=8+2 =10$,  so

$$v_2\left(\frac{50!}{25!25!}\right) = 47-2\cdot22=3 \\
v_3\left(\frac{50!}{25!25!}\right) = 22-2\cdot 10=2 $$

and only $2$ available powers of $3$ means that $v_{18}\left(\frac{50!}{25!25!}\right)=1$ - the highest power of $18$ dividing the given expression is $18^1=18$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:Use the [de polignac formula](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-6bqhrvvQAhWIvY8KHZn7CBIQFggnMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDe_Polignac%27s_formula&usg=AFQjCNEe_WfHWmh0piO8l2SplUqlzOzw_A&bvm=bv.142059868,d.c2I). As written first, answer was a little vague with many errors (I forgot that initially de polignac formula is used to find highest power of primes and 18 is not a prime). I m presenting a new one now.

Since $18=2\times 3\times3$ (Prime factorisation). So, a better idea is just to find the highest power of $2,3,3$ in the numerator and denominator. Then  just subtract the number of powers of $2,3,3$ in denominator from the number of powers of $2,3,3$ in numerator. Arrange the remaining powers in such a manner so that they form highest possible power of $18$. That will be the answer.

Comment: why downvote???

Comment: Hmm. If we had $\dfrac{36}{6\cdot6}$ instead, then you seem to suggest that because $36$ is divisible by $18$, but neither of the sixes is, the fraction would be divisible by $18$ also? I didn't downvote, but this is incomplete, and not very helpful in that something tells me not all readers will know of that divisibility formula at all, and even those who do, won't recognize it by that name. Particularly because Lulu already gave a link to an on-site description of the formula.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I thought de polignac formula work for factorials only. So there must be one of two things happening. 1.you missed the factorial sign 2.formula is wrong. ???? Which is the case?? Regards

Comment: The formula works for factorials only. But I thought you would see the error in your thinking if I used simpler numbers in that example. HINT: 18 is not a prime.

Comment: But, since you insist, consider
$$\frac{6!}{3!3!}.$$ The numerator is a multiple of $18$, neither of the factorials in the denominator is. Yet the fraction is not divisible by $18$ because it is not divisible by three.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so I think my answer is valid only if numerator and denominator, both are greater than 18.

Comment: I doubt it. You need to calculate divisibility by powers of two and three separately, and then use uniqueness of factorization to see how high a power of 18 will appear.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Okay, let me do that thing in my answer, I shall ping you whenever it is done and please reply me after that whether it is correct or not.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I identified what a little mistake I was making and now I have transformed my answer. Please take a look at it.

Comment: The principle is now ok.