# How to find highest power of 56

Tags: number-theory, exponential-function, divisibility, factorial, fractions

How to find highest power of 56 that 433! is divided
I've tried to use that power is equals to 433/56, but it is obviously not enough

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062262/what-is-the-highest-power-of-18-contained-in-frac502550-25/2062308).

Comment: There are 428 multiples of 2 (142 multiples of 8) and 70 multiples of 7 in $433!$, $min(142,70)=70$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate $$\left\lfloor\frac{433}{7}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{433}{7^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{433}{7^3}\right\rfloor.$$
I got $70$.

Thus, it's enough to check that $433!$ is divisible by $2^{3\cdot70}$, which is obvious because
$$\left\lfloor\frac{433}{2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{433}{2^2}\right\rfloor+...>210.$$
Id est, $433!$ is divisible by $56^{70}$ and $70$ is a maximal power.

Comment: do I need also to divide 433 by powers of 8?

Comment: @Student No, because $433!$ would naturally be divisible by $8$ more times as you also have factors of $4$ and $2$ contributing with factors of $8$ in $433!$. Technically you have to, but you realize that this will become higher when you take this into account.