# Proving Kummer Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Here is the theorem that way it was given to me...

> Show that the highest power of a prime $p$ dividing the binomial coefficient
>   ${n\choose m}$ equals the number of carries when $m$ is added to $n-m$, [EDIT] *in base $p$.

How do you go about proving this? I looked around and it seems the proof requires Legendre's formula but I'm not familiar with it. I'm not good with binomial coefficients and identities to begin with and I was given an example of this using binary code but I don't have any experience with that so I'm still lost.

If this is a duplicate question than I apologize in advance.

Comment: $n! = \prod_p p^{\sum_{k \ge 1} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor}$

Comment: this question was asked on Stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833706/highest-power-of-prime-p-dividing-binommnn). there are also Wikipedia articles on [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) and [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) which may be helpful.