# How to prove that $n$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$ if $n$ is prime?

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, primality-test

I want to prove that n divides $\binom{n}{k}$ and so I expanded the term to 
$\frac{n(n-1)..(n-k+1)}{k!}$. Clearly $n$ divides the numerator and also $n$ is relatively prime to all of the terms in the denominator and so $n$ is not divisible by $k!$. I'm struggling with how to approach that $\frac{(n-1)..(n-k+1)}{k!}$ is integer.

This problem comes as an example in the book I'm reading and supposedly it's obvious but I don't see it.

Edit: Sorry adding that we must have $1 \leq k \leq n-1$.

Comment: Using [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) should work.

Comment: If $m=pr$ is an integer divisible by the prime $p$, then $r$ is an integer.

Comment: $n$ does not divide $\dbinom{n}{k}$ in general.

Comment: In general, if $d$ divides $ab$ and $d$ has no factors in common with $a$, then $d$ divides $b$ (i.e. $b/d$ is an integer).  This is easy to see from unique factorization though there are more elementary proofs.

Comment: Also follows from [Kummer's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833706/highest-power-of-prime-p-dividing-binommnn), at least if $k$ is in certain range.

Comment: Does $3$ divide $\binom{3}{3}$?